# Apply CSS to iframe that is loaded trough JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can we change the styling of a iframe that is loaded trough JavaScript?

The script is loaded trough:

We would like to hide a navigation bar with class `.navbar`

Already tried the following but that does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   let myiFrame = document.querySelector('iframe');
   let doc = myiFrame.contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>.navbar {display:none !important;}</style>';
}
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `myiFrame.style.display = "none"`

Comment: Possible duplicate, please check here, it might contain the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe